# Difficulty implementing the teapot protocol

Tags: php, apache, google-app-engine, http

I am attempting to implement HTTP Client Error 418 on my website and running into difficulty. I have tried an implementation in PHP:

```
http_response_code(418);
```

which gives me a 500 error both in APACHE locally on my Mac and on Google App Engine where my website is deployed. Because Google has [implemented this protocol](http://www.google.com/teapot) I assumed that this would be relatively simple in one of their systems, but I am stuck. My site is not a coffee pot as defined in IETF [RFC 2324](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324) so I am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `http_response_code` function apparently [isn't written](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to handle a 418 meaning you have to write it yourself:

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
header($protocol . " 418 I'm a teapot");
$GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = 418;
```

Which I have verified works both locally with APACHE and on Google App Engine.